# extracting just the bandwidth value using regex

Tags: python, regex, awk, sed

How can I extract the just the Bandwidth value from the following dump

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.2 port 51725
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.7 GBytes  9.17 Gbits/sec
[  5] local 192.168.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.2 port 51726
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.7 GBytes  9.17 Gbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.2 port 51727
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.6 GBytes  9.10 Gbits/sec
[  5] local 192.168.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.2 port 51728
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.4 GBytes  8.91 Gbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.2 port 51729
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.8 GBytes  9.23 Gbits/sec
[  5] local 192.168.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.2 port 51730
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.7 GBytes  9.22 Gbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.2 port 51731
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.7 GBytes  9.23 Gbits/sec
[  5] local 192.168.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.2 port 51732
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.7 GBytes  9.16 Gbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.2 port 51733
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.6 GBytes  9.13 Gbits/sec
[  5] local 192.168.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.2 port 51734
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.5 GBytes  9.02 Gbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.2 port 51735
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.3 GBytes  8.85 Gbits/sec
```

My expected output is

```
9.17,9.17,9.10,8.91,9.23,9.22,9.23,9.16,9.13,9.02,8.95
```

I only have tried to do this with python, but I wish to know other faster and simpler approaches to do extract this detail.

Comment: Define "faster". I came up with a regex that does it in 76ms.

Comment: i have a large dataset, so ms is acceptable. I just want it have a smaller footprint in terms of processing.

Comment: We don't have anyway to determine that unless you show us what you tried.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex? Is there some reason that simpler pattern matching or field splitting shouldn't be used?

Comment: I am not sticking to regex. I am open to simpler pattern matching. Any suggestions.

Comment: Also, please let us know [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/). Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: if you have `grep` with `pcre` option, try `grep -oP '[0-9.]+(?=\s*Gbits)' file | paste -sd,` assuming all are `Gbits`

Comment: @Sundeep if you had it this as an answer, I would accept yours. Thanks

Comment: Alas, this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). @user2532296, are you only interested in figuring out how to implement your solution, rather than solving this problem in a better way? Also, sundeep's answer does not use python, awk or sed (code for which you have yet to add to your question). If you're interested in reducing the downvotes on your question, you might want to clean that up.

Comment: yes, I believe in an iterative approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` will be a good candidate

```
$ awk -v ORS="," '$8 == "Gbits/sec"{print $7}' file
9.17,9.17,9.10,8.91,9.23,9.22,9.23,9.16,9.13,9.02,8.85,
```

---

**What it does?**

- `-v ORS=","` Sets the output record separator as `,`. This makes the each `print` to be separated by `,`.
- `'$8 == "Gbits/sec"` Checks if the 8th column matches `Gbits/sec`, if yes print the the 7 field which is the bandwith

---

If you are worried about the last `,` then we can write,

```
$ awk -v ORS="" '$8 == "Gbits/sec"{print sep$7; sep=","} END{print "\n"}' file
```

---

**Edit**

As @mklement0 has pointed out, this may fail if the start of the line is filled up like say `[111]`. In that case we can rewrite as,

```
$ awk -v ORS="" '$NF == "Gbits/sec"{print sep$(NF-1); sep=","} END{print "\n"}' file
```

Here, `NF` is the number of fields/columns in each line. So `$NF` will be the last field and `$(NF-1)` will be the second last column.

Comment: Your test on `$8` is against the entire string in the sample input. You can save some processing time if you use `==` instead of `~`. (While a string is a regex, it can also be just-a-string.)

Comment: @ghoti Yeah, I don't know why but it didn't work me for the first time, so I thought of skipping. I have corrected in answer. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @mklement0 Very good point. I didn't think that much. Have edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @EdMorton I have corrected the issue with `-v` and new line. Hope it is fine now. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

With `grep` if `pcre` option is available

```
$ grep -oP '[0-9.]+(?=\s*Gbits)' ip.txt | paste -sd,
9.17,9.17,9.10,8.91,9.23,9.22,9.23,9.16,9.13,9.02,8.85
```

- `[0-9.]+` numbers to extract
- `(?=\s*Gbits)` only if it is followed by optional spaces and the text `Gbits`
- then use `paste` command to combine the output to single line with `,` as delimiter

From `man grep` and `man paste`

> grep, egrep, fgrep, rgrep - print lines matching a pattern
>
> -o, --only-matching
>         Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
>
> -P, --perl-regexp
>         Interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE).  This is highly experimental and  grep  -P  may
>         warn of unimplemented features.
>
> paste - merge lines of files
>
> -s, --serial
>         paste one file at a time instead of in parallel
>
> -d, --delimiters=LIST
>         reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs